# How do i pass a variable for the query in a get Manager call?

Tags: perl, mason, rose-db-object

I am trying to make a simple Rose DB call:
$id = xyz;
$name = "company";

```
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable( query =>[ id => $id, name => $name ] );
```

in it possible to not have the whole query written every time, and declare it like a string variable such that i can just call

```
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable( query =>[ $query ] );
```

where $query = qq { id => $id , name => $name };

Please Help

Comment: This argument (`query =>[ id => $id, name => $name ]` ) looks like a hash with key `query` holding an array. Is it so?

Comment: yup. the best way i could state it is, "hash of a hash called query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually i figured out how to do that . Its not that complicated. Only thing is  RoseDB objects expect an array reference for a query. So something like this works :

my @query = ( id => $id, name => $name );

```
testDB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable( query => \@query );
```

Just thought would answer it myself, incase someonelse is looking for a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

By what **I understood** from your question, I am giving this answer.
Try this one.

```
my $myquery = {query =>{ id=>$id, name=>$name }} ;

TGI::testTable::Manager->get_testTable($myquery);
```

Hope, this gives some idea to you.

**Edit for "Hash with Array reference":**

```
my $myquery = [ id=>$id, name=>$name ] ;

TGI::testTable::Manager->get_testTable(query => $myquery);
```

check out this : [How to pass a a string variable as "query" for get Manager call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678683/how-to-pass-a-a-string-variable-as-query-for-get-manager-call)