# How to pass a a string variable as "query" for get Manager call?

Tags: perl, mason, rose-db-object

I'm trying to make this simple call:

```
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable( query => [ id => $id, name => $name ] )
```

which works perfectly fine. But is it possible to pass a variable for the query. Something like:

```
$query = "id => $id , name => $name";
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable( query => [ $query ] );
```

or something similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i pass a variable for the query in a get Manager call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678236/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-for-the-query-in-a-get-manager-call)

Answer (score 1):

Strings and complex data structures are completely different things.

Strings are a sequence of codepoints/graphemes/bytes (depends how you're looking). Strings are dumb. Strings are not good at containing complex and/or hierarchical data. (Point in case: XML is pure pain)

However, you can put any Perl data structure into a scalar variable, using references. Square brackets create a reference to an anonymous array.

These groups of lines are equivalent except for the fact that a variable name is introduced:

```
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable( query   => [ id => $id, name => $name ] );

my @query = (id => $id, name => $name);
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable(query => \@query); # the "\" takes a reference to a value

my @query = (id => $id, name => $name);
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable(query => [@query]); # using "[]" to make the arrayref. The reference points to a copy of @query.

# this solution is probably best:
my $query = [ id => $id, name => $name ]; # "[]" makes an arrayref
DataB::testTable::Manager->get_testTable(query => $query);
```

Using references to data structures is better than using strings.

(You could interpret a string as Perl source code via `eval`. This is extremely powerful, but not everything stringifies to a form that can be eval'd into an equivalent data structure. Don't use string-eval, except for well thought out metaprogramming.)

For further info on references and complex data structures, [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) might be interesting.